# enable a jcombobox without pressing enter

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtextfield, enter

I am working in java swing in netbeans.

I have a textfield. I would like that a combobox will be enabled only if the text written in the textfield is greatter tahn one. 
My code works if I press the enter key. But I would like to make it work just by writting in the textfield. How can I do this?

```
 private void nmrintervTXTActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    String text = this.nmrintervTXT.getText();
    System.out.println(text);
    if (!text.isEmpty()) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(text) > 1) {
            this.evidenceOtherApplicantsTXT.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See [How to Write a Document Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html).

Answer (score 0):

See [addCaretListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#addCaretListener(javax.swing.event.CaretListener)) API.

```
textfield.addCaretListener(new CaretListener() {
    @Override
    public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e) {
        System.out.println("caretUpdate with new text: "+textfield.getText());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

class MyDocumentListener implements DocumentListener {

```
    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent e) {
        update(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent e) {
        update(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent e) {
    }

    public void update(javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent e) {
        String text = nmrintervTXT.getText();
        try {
            evidenceOtherApplicantsTXT.setEnabled(Integer.parseInt(text) > 1);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            evidenceOtherApplicantsTXT.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}

public MyClass() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    nmrintervTXT = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    nmrintervTXT.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new MyDocumentListener());
```

I think the parameter e was in fault in update in MyDocumentListener.